# What's the deal with the Enthusiast badge?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, badges

I was just looking at the Enthusiast badge and noticed that many of the users who earned it have quite low reputation. Many in fact have the "base reputation" of 101, with no questions or answers.

Have these people really visited the site every day for a month and not contributed in any way? Just wondering if maybe there's a bug here or something?

Comment: You know it does seem like the logic is not ideal on that badge. Case in point, I visited the site on each of the last several calendar days (conscientious of the badge, I'll admit). At some point, though, I seemed to have missed logging consecutive days, though. Does it look for visits no more than 24 hours apart, or define a day as 0:00 to 23:59 for that person, or based on GMT? Just curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's also possible to game this badge if you have some sort of browser extension that automatically loads sites all the time.

We have some rudimentary protection in place for this, but it's the kind of thing where an arms race to try to make the badge more strict would just cause more harm than help.

Answer (score 4):

The daily visits are all that is required. There is no requirement for actually participating.

Comment: I know that - I just find it odd that someone can visit this site for 30 days straight and not contribute in any way. I mean, I contribute to the site plenty and even I don't visit every day...

Comment: I don't find it surprising at all that there are lurkers out there who just browse to find something interesting or learn something. Lots of people could feel that they don't have something to contribute or a specific question to ask.

Comment: Grant, define "daily." See my comment/answer on this question -- I lost my streak, but visited within 24 hour periods.

Comment: @ghoppe Indeed, I often lurk, absorbing as much of the content as I can. Only occasionally do I have anything worth adding to the conversation!

Comment: @Chris Adragna I visit two or three times a day. Admittedly I do this with an eye towards the Fanatic badge, but also to find interesting content. I have had days inexplicably (sp?) disappear, even when I'm sure I made at least one visit on the day. This seems to happen across the sites I frequent.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's necessarily a bug. I often come here and don't say much and I bet a lot of people do the same thing. Many people using SE sites may just browse questions, find an answer they're looking for without necessarily participating. Just the usual lurker behavior.